# Exec ruby cmd error with PHP

Tags: php, ruby, aws-sdk, fuelphp

Here is my environment.

- PHP version: 5.5.23
- Framework: fuelPHP
- Ruby: 2.3.0

My Ruby script requires `aws-sdk`. I want to call ruby script as it works on Putty, for example like this:

```
ruby filelist.rb
```

I tried it giving absolute path for Ruby and the script file. It works on Putty, but not when I call it from PHP. I get this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- aws-sdk-s3 (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require''
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/komiyak/20150603/1433364444) is a solution. It's in Japanese, but you can translate it to read.